# Values of $n$ so that exist a matrix $A\neq 0$ so that $Ax$ is orthogonal a $x$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

Find the values of $n$ so that exist a matrix $A\neq 0$ with reals entries so that $Ax$ is orthogonal a $x$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I try solved this exercise using the theory of orthogonal matrix of my course but I not can't prove this exercise.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is it possible to make an example or address a link for your question? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One needs to restrict $A$ to be nonsingular, lest we have $Ax = 0$ for some $0 \ne x \in \Bbb R^n$ and the issue of the orthogonality of $x$ and $Ax$ becomes meaningless (I assume orthogonality is technically undefined for zero vectors).  If we so assume, then:

There exists a real $n \times n$ nonsingular matrix with

$\langle x, Ax \rangle = 0, \; \forall 0 \ne x \in \Bbb R^n \tag 1$

if and only if $n$ is even, to wit:

Let $J$ be the $2 \times 2$ matrix

$J = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}; \tag 2$

for $y \in \Bbb R^2$, we have

$y = \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{pmatrix}; \tag 3$

then

$Jy = \begin{pmatrix} -y_2 \\ y_1 \end{pmatrix}; \tag 4$

thus

$\langle y, Jy \rangle = y^TJy = -y_1y_2 + y_2y_1 = 0; \tag 5$

if $n = 2m$ is even, we can choose $A$ to be the block diagonal matrix consisting of $m$ blocks, each equal to $J$, thus:

$A = \begin{bmatrix} J & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & J & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & J \end{bmatrix}; \tag 6$

each block of $J$ then operates on $(x_{2i + 1}, x_{2i + 2})^T$, $0 \le i \le m - 1$, exactly as $J$ operates on $y$; thus

$\langle x, Ax \rangle = 0, \; \forall x \in \Bbb R^n; \tag 7$

this shows the existence of the requisite $A$ when $n = 2m$.  If, on the other hand $n$ is odd, then since the characteristic polynomial $A -\lambda I$ is of odd degree, $A$ has at least one real eigenvalue $\rho$; then

$Ax = \rho x \tag 8$

for some $x \ne 0$; thus,

$\langle x, Ax \rangle = \langle x, \rho x \rangle = \rho \langle x, x, \rangle \ne 0, \tag 9$

since the nonsingularity $A$ implies $\rho \ne 0$; every nonsingular $A$ of odd size thus fails to sastisfy $\langle x, Ax \rangle = 0$ for some $x$.

Comment: ...can be $A$ a symmetric matrix?

Comment: @LuisPrado:  no, since symmetric matrices can be diagonalized; $A \ne 0$ implies $A$ has a non-zero eigenvalue $\mu$ with $Av = \mu v$ for some $v$; then $\langle v, Av \rangle = \langle v, \mu v \rangle = \mu \langle v, v \rangle \ne 0$.

Comment: Nice!...thanks @Robert Lewis...